# Align to pixel grid problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, vector

I'm designing small icons for screen, I'm using align to pixel grid. One problem I've encountered is aligning a compound path to the grid.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem]

This is the letter "O", which is a compound path, when I align to grid, it messes things up. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see the problem here in CS6. What version are you using? Are you scaling Strokes & Effects as well?

Comment: The cutout of the "O" gets filled in and the outside path is removed. I just want the object align to pixel gird. I'm not doing any scaling/resizing.

Comment: I see what you are experiencing. Just not experiencing it here. Are you ticking the Scale Strokes & Effects option as well?

Comment: ticked and unticked, both have the same result :(

Comment: What illustrator version? How is the object constructed? The more information you can provide, the more help people can be.

Comment: cs5, here is the file: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3127508/compound_path_problem.ai)

Comment: Can't beat a bit of all caps Eurostile Bold Extended (where appropriate of course)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem when using the dialog's "Align to Pixel Grid" checkbox, but not when using the flyout menu instead ("Align New Objects to Pixel Grid").  Also, when I released the compound paths and tried applying the aforementioned checkbox to each part individually - it's the larger OUTSIDE shape that's freaking out, not the inner one.  May I suggest you rebuild that shape and try again?  There's seems to be some funky error in it (when I made new shapes, they worked fine).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the perfect answer, but it might get you through the project.

Duplicate the layer. Then flatten it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't trust Illustrator's own align to pixel grid options, they have too many side effects, consequences and quirks.

I prefer the [Wundes](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) script [**PixelAlign**](https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/pixelAlign.jsx), which works more like the buttons in the Align palette - you hit it once, it does its thing, the shapes are aligned to the pixel grid once, and then nothing else happens. No surprises.

I can't guarantee it'll fix this problem, as it seems to be a strange problem that is difficult to replicate, but this is something worth trying for anyone with pixel grid problems.

[Direct download link](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/pixelAlign.jsx).

Comment: THANK YOU! This is a wonderful way to align to pixels without distorting and to align text! Have I said thank you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apply a 2px stroke (inside) first, then switch to a 1px stroke. For some reason Illustrator will keep the object aligned to the pixel grid then. Quirk for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the problem here at all.

I'd suggest resetting the Illustrator preferences. and then relaunching Illustrator to try again. Instructions on resetting preferences can be found [on Adobe's Site here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-630ca.html)

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work, I've linked the file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3127508/compound_path_problem.ai)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a centred stroke. In Illustrator, the stroke position and size affect the path's position, when pixel snapping is turned on.

[image: Illustrator stroke width and pixel snapping]

Odd stroke widths (1px, 3px etc) snap differently to even stroke widths (2px, 4px etc). The same rules apply to compound paths.

[image: Compound paths and pixel snapping]

Often, a good solution is to just draw separate paths.

[image: Illustrator path pixel snapping]

Comment: Check the link in the question comments.. it's a standard compound path.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what kind of path it is, they all play by the same rules.

Comment: paths yes... compound shapes.. no. Again.. check the file linked in the comments of the question.

Comment: Compound paths, yes. I've edited my answer to include compound path examples.

Comment: Replicate the users issue with the supplied file. You're missing the problem entirely. Not stating what you post is incorrect, it's merely off in left field.

Comment: The example file isn't remotely pixel snapped, so yes, I'm struggling to see what the OP is after.

Comment: Yes. That was my point.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because of the size. I am also having a similar (may be the same) problem. when scaling down a compound object it gets weird below about 300px. I suppose this version of illustrator has some bugs. Hope they fix it soon.